# Como mandar datos de un dataGrid que esta en constante cambio a una tabla de SQL

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

esta en constante cambio por que obtiene su informacion con diferentes archivos de excel.
 con este codigo.

```
public partial class PM : Form
{
    private BindingSource bindingsource1 = new BindingSource();
    private SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
    SqlConnection conexion = new SqlConnection("");
    SqlDataAdapter da;
    DataSet ds;
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    //SqlCommandBuilder builder;

    public PM()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void LLenarGrid(string archivo, string hoja)
    {
        //declaramos las variables         
        OleDbConnection conexion = null;
        DataSet dataSet = null;
        OleDbDataAdapter dataAdapter = null;
        string consultaHojaExcel = "Select * from [" + hoja + "$]";
        //esta cadena es para archivos excel 2007 y 2010
        string cadenaConexionArchivoExcel = "provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source='" + archivo + "';Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;";
        //para archivos de 97-2003 usar la siguiente cadena
        //string cadenaConexionArchivoExcel = "provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source='" + archivo + "';Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;";
        //Validamos que el usuario ingrese el nombre de la hoja del archivo de excel a leer
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(hoja))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("No hay una hoja para leer");
        }
        else
        {
            try
            {
                //Si el usuario escribio el nombre de la hoja se procedera con la busqueda
                conexion = new OleDbConnection(cadenaConexionArchivoExcel);//creamos la conexion con la hoja de excel
                conexion.Open(); //abrimos la conexion
                dataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(consultaHojaExcel, conexion); //traemos los datos de la hoja y las guardamos en un dataSdapter
                dataSet = new DataSet(); // creamos la instancia del objeto DataSet
                dataAdapter.Fill(dataSet, hoja);//llenamos el dataset
                dataGridView1.DataSource = dataSet.Tables[0]; //le asignamos al DataGridView el contenido del dataSet
                conexion.Close();//cerramos la conexion
                dataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = false;       //eliminamos la ultima fila del datagridview que se autoagrega
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //en caso de haber una excepcion que nos mande un mensaje de error
                MessageBox.Show("Error, Verificar el archivo o el nombre de la hoja", ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }


     private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //creamos un objeto OpenDialog que es un cuadro de dialogo para buscar archivos
        OpenFileDialog dialog = new OpenFileDialog();
        dialog.Filter = "Archivos de Excel (*.xls;*.xlsx)|*.xls;*.xlsx"; //le indicamos el tipo de filtro en este caso que busque
        //solo los archivos excel
        dialog.Title = "Seleccione el archivo de Excel";//le damos un titulo a la ventana
        dialog.FileName = string.Empty;//inicializamos con vacio el nombre del archivo
        //si al seleccionar el archivo damos Ok
        if (dialog.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {
            //el nombre del archivo sera asignado al textbox
            textBox1.Text = dialog.FileName;
            string hoja = textBox2.Text; //la variable hoja tendra el valor del textbox donde colocamos el nombre de la hoja
            LLenarGrid(textBox1.Text, hoja); //se manda a llamar al metodo
            dataGridView1.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill; //se ajustan las
            //columnas al ancho del DataGridview para que no quede espacio en blanco (opcional)
        }
    }
```

eso ya funciona, pero no encuentro la manera de estar mandando la informacion que se ponga en mi dataGridView a mi tabla de sql server, por que puedo seleccionar un archivo que solo tenga 4, 5,100, etc numero de columnas, nunca van a ser las mismas, osea ahorita puedo tener en mi datagridview informacion con 4 columnas y las puedo guardar en mi tabla de sql server si fuesen fijas, pero quiero que cuando mi datagrid tenga no se 50 columnas esa misma tabla que se guardo con 4 columnas ahora en lugar de las 4 se guarden las 50, o la x cantidad que exista.

Mi jefe solo quiere seleccionar el archivo de excel que el desee, pasarlo al datagrid y de el datagrid a la tabla de sql Server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fácil, crea una tabla con la siguien estructura:

`id`<- autonumeric int que sera la llave

`xml`<- campo de tipo XML (aquí esta la magia)

En el campo XML guarda el la información del datagridview convertida a XML, no importa el numero de columnas, puedes guardar cualquier XML.

NOTA: Tendrás que ver si tu versión de SQL soporta XML.

Para convertir el `datagridview` a `XML`:

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet(); 
DataTable dt = (DataTable)gridview.DataSource;// Conviertelo a un datatable
ds.Tables.Add(dt);
string xml = ds.GetXml();//el dataset tiene la funcion para obtener el string del XML
```

Ese parámetro se lo mandas al `SQL`:

```
public void GuardarXml(int id, string xml)
{
// query sql
string insertQuery = "INSERT INTO tabla(id, xml) VALUES (@id, @xml)";

using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Tu Cadena de conexion"))
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(insertQuery, conn))
{
    // define parameters
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = id;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@xml", SqlDbType.Xml, xml.Length).Value = xml;

    // open connection, execute query, close connection
    conn.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    conn.Close();
}
}
```

Después para obtener los datos... debes hacer lo mismo que hice pero a la inversa:

1. Obtener el campo `XML` desde `SQL`
2. Convertirlo a un `Dataset`, y después obtener el `DataTable`

   ```
    StringReader reader= new StringReader(xmlData);
    DataSet ds= new DataSet();
    ds.ReadXml(reader);

    var dt = ds.Tables[0];
   ```
3. Mostrarlo en el `DataGridView`, `gridView.Datasource = dt;`

**Si no quieres enviar el ID puedes cambiar el código:**

```
public void GuardarXml( string xml)//Quitar el id de aqui
{
// query sql
string insertQuery = "INSERT INTO tabla(id, xml) VALUES (@id, @xml)";

using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Tu Cadena de conexion"))
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(insertQuery, conn))
{
    // define parameters
    //cmd.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = id;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@xml", SqlDbType.Xml, xml.Length).Value = xml;

    // open connection, execute query, close connection
    conn.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    conn.Close();
}
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, comenzare a realizarlo de esa manera, soy nueva en esto y tengo 2 meses atorada con eso jaja

Comment: XD ok, no te preocupes para eso esta la comunidad para apoyarnos, "nadie nace enseñado"

Comment: Disculpa de donde tomas el id?, en un boton coloque el dataset y mande a llamar el metodo GuardarXml y me dice que el id no aparece en el contexto actual

Comment: Mmmm podrías poner el id como identity en la BD y no enviarlo... o enviar siempre un 0 (cero), con no enviarlo me refiero a comentar esas lineas... y quitarlo del método guardar XML